# Postman can't get response from Nodejs when content-length is over 1024

Tags: node.js, postman

I'm building a simple API with Nodejs

I want to response some token and its pretty long

Here is my code

```
router.get("", (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
  // res.removeHeader("Content-Length");
  return res.status(200).send({
    message: "HelloWorld",
    token:
      "{long text}",
  });
});
```

it keep showing error [Parse Error: The server returned a malformed response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c0ngd.png)

I figured out that when the content-lenght is over 1024, it can't show

But when i use `curl`, i still get the response no matter content-length is

**Update**

I was using `compression`

`app.use(compression());`

When i remove it i got the reponse but i still don't know why

Comment: See https://github.com/expressjs/compression/issues/182

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue you're experiencing is related to using compression middleware in your Express application. Compression middleware (such as the one provided by the compression package) reduces bandwidth usage by compressing response bodies before sending them to clients.

"Parse Error: The server returned a malformed response," may occur because the client (or an intermediate server) cannot correctly decompress the response due to an incorrect Content-Length.

Here are a few things you can consider:

-Remove Content-Length Modification:

-Compression Middleware Configuration:

```
const compression = require('compression');
const express = require('express');
const app = express();

app.use(compression());
```

- Check Curl Responses:

If curl can receive the response correctly regardless of the Content-Length, the issue might be specific to how certain clients or servers are handling compressed responses.   Ensure that the clients experiencing issues are configured to handle compressed responses correctly

- Update Compression Middleware: